# I would like to copy my iphone SMS from one backup to another

Tags: iphone, sms, restore

I recently have had to do a full restore to factory setting on my iPhone and now i want to copy my SMS messages from an old backup into a new backup made from the restored phone. I need to do this as the old backups cause my phone to crash regularly.

I have retrieved my original sms backup file 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28 from  C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\ and would like to copy it into the latest backup. When i try, the restore fails and itunes says it's corrupt.

When i open the file (in windows or mac or ubuntu) to view the data, i can see a lot of what looks like junk characters.

I cannot open the file in SQLite either.

The file must be okay, as if i do restore the old backup to the phone i can see the messages.

Anybody have similar experience and solution?

Comment: 1.Why cant you use iTunes  2. Why did you ask this question in Stackoverflow.com?

Comment: how is this a programming question?

Comment: Probably need to move this question over to http://apple.stackexchange.com/